# ASP.NET MVC Form and serializeArray() of jquery overriding checkbox's state with false

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, serialization

I have a simple form with MVC Html helpers with different types of fields, including a single checkbox.

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Filter.IncludeInactiveGifts)
```

this helper always generates two controls. Here you can see a case with checkbox selected:

```
<input class="check-box" id="Filter_IncludeInactiveGifts" name="Filter.IncludeInactiveGifts" type="checkbox" value="true">
<input name="Filter.IncludeInactiveGifts" type="hidden" value="false">
```

So when submitting a form builded with @Html.BeginForm everything is submitted fine and I always get true or false value for this checkbox. But in my case I have a telerik's grid on the page and I use jquery serializeArray() for serializing form and sending it with grid's Ajax DataBinding request, because I use this form as a filter for my grid.

Here's the js:

```
var Grid_onDataBinding = function(e) {
                var filterFields = {};
                var formSerialized = $filterForm.serializeArray();
                $.each(formSerialized, function(i, field) {
                    filterFields[field.name] = field.value;
                });

                e.data = filterFields;
            };
```

So because of MVC's helper creating two fields for the checkbox during the serialization I always get a false value from the second field. When data is passed to the controller the second value which is always false is binded to the model's property.

What is the best way to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

try first submiting the form without a call of serializeArray() and see if on the post you get the correct value of the checkbox.
after this you can try a ajax request and on the response try giving the datasource to the grid.